# Native crash affecting one Samsung device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vitals

Please can someone help me understand this native crash report from Google Play Console. It affects only one device, a Samsung Note10+. I have searched StackOverflow and there seems to be similar conflicts with Samsung devices.

Is this a case where I need to disable zipalign from using zopfli? Or is it some ProGuard rules file entry that I need? Thank you.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> myapp.name <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000011d1cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::mirror::Class::DescriptorEquals(char const*)+228)
  #01  pc 000000000014b71c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassTable::Lookup(char const*, unsigned long)+324)
  #02  pc 000000000011a20c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::LookupClass(art::Thread*, char const*, unsigned long, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+168)
  #03  pc 00000000003d9e58  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+208)
  #04  pc 000000000007c458  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass+200)
  #05  pc 000000000017f118  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass+104)
  #06  pc 000000000017f074  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass+52)
  #07  pc 00000000007df270  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication+64)
  #08  pc 0000000000067150  /data/app/myapp.name-KLtTyFCFD-SLaA5BMQu86g==/oat/arm64/base.odex (androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication+48)
  #09  pc 00000000007e8fc0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication+128)
  #10  pc 00000000007ef42c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication+460)
  #11  pc 00000000008eff88  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+6936)
  #12  pc 00000000008eb0d0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+6960)
  #13  pc 0000000000b1eea4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+180)
  #14  pc 0000000000b21fa0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1264)
  #15  pc 00000000008f6a78  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+680)
  #16  pc 000000000054c44c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
  #17  pc 00000000000d00b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
  #18  pc 00000000004549a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #19  pc 000000000045640c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)
  #20  pc 00000000003e7134  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52)
  #21  pc 000000000011f7e4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
  #22  pc 0000000000e0f948  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+136)
  #23  pc 0000000000e16948  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2312)
  #24  pc 000000000054c44c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+604)
  #25  pc 00000000000d00b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+232)
  #26  pc 00000000004549a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #27  pc 0000000000454600  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+424)
  #28  pc 000000000035dfcc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+768)
  #29  pc 00000000000ba474  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
  #30  pc 00000000000bd034  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+772)
  #31  pc 00000000000049cc  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1200)
  #32  pc 00000000000aee34  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar crash on Samsung devices (S7 & Tab A)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't solve this.  I haven't seen it since though, so I'm guessing it's a Samsung issue.